# Want empty textfield questions to not be input into database

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have a php questionare page which generates multiple questions from a database.  All of the questions are true false, but there are a few that have a fill text field in addtion (see picture).  If the fill in text field ('fill_in_quest_text') has text in it , the response and text are saved into the msyslq database.  But if there is no text in the textbox for the question, I don't want the response with it's accompanying question number submitted.  I think there is a simple solution, but I am not knowledgeable enough about php to figure out how to do it -- namely to only insert into the database the response when there is text in the text box.

Here's what the questions and fill in questions look like:

[image: screenshot of relevant part of question page]

Here is the relevant code that takes the responses from the _POST variable and puts them into the "responses" table.

```
foreach( $_POST['question'] as $key => $questionToInsert ) 
{
 $follow = ( isset($_POST['follow'][$key]) ) ? $_POST['follow'][$key] : '';
 $fill_in_quest_text = ( isset($_POST['fill_in_quest_text'][$key]) ) ?
    $_POST['fill_in_quest_text'][$key] : '';
 $q = ( isset($_POST['q'][$key]) ) ? $_POST['q'][$key] : '';

 $query = "insert into responses(userid,question_id,response_main,
    response_followup,category,response_time,unique_session,fill_in_quest_text)
    values('".$_SESSION['userid']."','".$_POST['question'][$key]."', '".$q."',
    '".$follow."','".$_POST["category"]."','".date("Y-m-d")."',
   '".$_SESSION['unique_session']."','".$fill_in_quest_text."')";

 mysql_query($query);
}
```

Here is the html from the browser that corresponds with the screenshot above.  (Sorry for the mess)

```
    <tr>
    <td width="70" valign="top"><input  type="radio" name="q[37]" value="yes" onClick='callme("q37","y","follow37")'> Yes
    <input type="hidden" name="question[37]" value="364"></td>
<td width="70" valign="top"><input type="radio" name="q[37]" value="no" onClick='callme("q37","n","follow37")' >    
  No</td>
  <td>I neither regret the past nor wish to close the door on it.</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td width="70" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
  <td width="70" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
  <td ><div id="q37" style="display:none">
<input type="checkbox" id="follow37" name="follow[37]" value="yes" >
I would like to work on this</div>
    <br>
        </td></tr>
    <tr>
  <td width="70" valign="top"><input  type="radio" name="q[38]" value="yes" onClick='callme("q38","y","follow38")'>
    Yes
    <input type="hidden" name="question[38]" value="365"></td>
  <td width="70" valign="top"><input type="radio" name="q[38]" value="no" onClick='callme("q38","n","follow38")' >    
  No</td>
  <td>I read meaningful texts and discuss them with others.</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td width="70" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
  <td width="70" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
  <td ><div id="q38" style="display:none">
<input type="checkbox" id="follow38" name="follow[38]" value="yes" >
I would like to work on this</div>
    <br>
        </td></tr>
    <tr>
  <td width="70" valign="top"><input  type="radio" name="q[39]" value="yes" onClick='callme("q39","y","follow39")'>
    Yes
    <input type="hidden" name="question[39]" value="366"></td>
  <td width="70" valign="top"><input type="radio" name="q[39]" value="no" onClick='callme("q39","n","follow39")' >    
  No</td>
  <td>Other:  <input style='font-size=13px;' type='text' size='90' name='fill_in_quest_text[39]'></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td width="70" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
  <td width="70" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
  <td ><div id="q39" style="display:none">
<input type="checkbox" id="follow39" name="follow[39]" value="yes" >
I would like to work on this</div>
    <br>
        </td></tr>
    <tr>
  <td width="70" valign="top"><input  type="radio" name="q[40]" value="yes" onClick='callme("q40","y","follow40")'>
    Yes
    <input type="hidden" name="question[40]" value="367"></td>
  <td width="70" valign="top"><input type="radio" name="q[40]" value="no" onClick='callme("q40","n","follow40")' >    
  No</td>
  <td>Other:  <input style='font-size=13px;' type='text' size='90' name='fill_in_quest_text[40]'></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td width="70" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
  <td width="70" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
  <td ><div id="q40" style="display:none">
<input type="checkbox" id="follow40" name="follow[40]" value="yes" >
I would like to work on this</div>
    <br>
        </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan="3"><input id="btns" type="submit" name="submit" value=" Submit " onClick="return countUAquestions()">&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <!-- <input type="button" name="button" value="Cancel" onClick="window.location.href='welcome_page.php'"> -->
    <input id="btns" type="button" name="button" value="  Cancel  " onClick="return jsconfirm()"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan="3" height="20">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
    </table>
    <input type="hidden" name="category" value="Spiritual_Wellness">
    <input type="hidden" name="total_questions" value="40">
  </form>
</div>
```

Let me know if I need to supply more detail.  I think it can be done with JavaScript as well, but couldn't quite figure that out either.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to simply check the "truthiness" of your input. This will eliminate responses like the empty string `""`, which is what you're likely getting from the empty inputs.

Try modifying your code as follows:

```php
$q = ( isset($_POST['q'][$key]) ) ? $_POST['q'][$key] : '';

// Don't store "falsy" $q
if ($q)
{
  $query = "insert into responses(userid, question_id, response_main, response_followup, category, response_time, unique_session, fill_in_quest_text) values ('".$_SESSION['userid']."','".$_POST['question'][$key]."', '".$q."', '".$follow."','".$_POST["category"]."','".date("Y-m-d")."', '".$_SESSION['unique_session']."','".$fill_in_quest_text."')";

  mysql_query($query);
}
```

## UPDATE

According to OP's comment, if you want to save *some* of the fields which may be empty, you'll need to inform PHP somehow. By default, PHP has no way of knowing what type of input a piece of data is coming from. One way to implement this could be the following:

```html
<input type="text" name="no_save">

<input type="checkbox" name="yes_save" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="force_save[]" value="yes_save">

<input type="checkbox" name="yes_save2" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="force_save[]" value="yes_save2">
```

The idea here is to build an array of the inputs we want to force storage in the DB. Then we just check if the input key is in the `force_save` array:

```php
// this line:
if ($q) {}
// becomes:
if ($q || in_array($key, $_POST['force_save'])) {}
```

Comment: Thanks Jon.  This almost works -- it prevents the questions with the empty text boxes from being submitted.  However I DO want the regular (non-text boxed) questions to be submitted even if they aren't answered, and this no longer happens with the $q test.
If necessary, I can use a field in the question table that is called "isfillinquestion".  It has a 1 if it's a fill in question and 0 if it isn't, but I'm hoping there is an easier way similar to what you suggested.

Comment: PHP won't receive any information about the type of fields that the posted data comes from. You'll either need to hard code the logic, or provide that information in another field. I'll update with a possible solution in my answer.

Comment: Okay.  I used your idea with the hidden input field and added the following field to my form for the questions that have a fill in box:
echo "<input type='hidden' name='is_fill_in[$i]' value='yes'>";
And for the questions that don't have a fill in field, they get the same tag but value of 'no'.  I then test the value when processing the form data as you suggested.  It works.  A miracle.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do it :)

```
     foreach( $_POST['question'] as $key => $questionToInsert ) 
        {
         $follow = ( isset($_POST['follow'][$key]) ) ? $_POST['follow'][$key] : '';
         $fill_in_quest_text = ( isset($_POST['fill_in_quest_text'][$key]) ) ?
            $_POST['fill_in_quest_text'][$key] : '';
         $q = ( isset($_POST['q'][$key]) ) ? $_POST['q'][$key] : '';

        if($q){
          if(isset($_POST['fill_in_quest_text'][$key]) && $_POST['fill_in_quest_text'][$key]==''){
          //skip
          }else{
            echo 'do'.$_POST['question'][$key].'<br/>'; //for debug purpose
           $query = "insert into responses(userid,question_id,response_main,
              response_followup,category,response_time,unique_session,fill_in_quest_text)
              values('".$_SESSION['userid']."','".$_POST['question'][$key]."', '".$q."',
              '".$follow."','".$_POST["category"]."','".date("Y-m-d")."',
             '".$_SESSION['unique_session']."','".$fill_in_quest_text."')";

          mysql_query($query);
          }
      }

        }
```

Comment: Thanks @TrueSkillZ.  However I don't know how to print_r the contents of the $_POST['question'] variable as the code that I submitted is not in a viewable part of the html page.  The 'question' variable however is just the integer for the question ID.

Regarding your JavaScript solution, I don't understand how I integrate that into my code.  Is that inline code that I would put with the Submit button?  Thanks.

Comment: You would just copy the code above into you HTML and click the submit button. It would check all the fields if they are empty and disable them. You don't need to put anything in the submit button, that code goes any where and it will auto detect the form submition. Could you give the HTML output of the image you included? I would then see all the the details I need to write the final PHP code. You can incldue the HTML output in the question :)

Comment: I added the html to my question above.
Regarding the javascript you provided, I put it in the <head> area of the document, and added the jquery source url, but it did not seem to have any effect.  Note that I DO already have a few javascript functions so I don't know if that would interfere with it working.  I couldn't figure out how to tell if the code was running or not.

Comment: Updated the question with the php solution. Simply added the code "if(isset($_POST['fill_in_quest_text'][$key])&&$_POST['fill_in_quest_text'][$key]==''){" it checks if there is a text input and if it's there and it's empty skips it :) tested and working on my end :)

Comment: Thanks @TrueSkillZ, but it seems to be treating the test as always false and it executes the query on every question.  I experimented with the empty() function to no avail.   If I use the first part of your test alone (the isset()) it inserts every question except the one with the text in the box.  And if I use only the second part of the test ($_POST['fill_in_quest_text'][$key]=='') it inserts only the question with the filled in text box and no others.

Comment: I think I'm kind of lost now :D Just to clarify: you want questions that have the text input and are not empty to execute the query and everything else do nothing?

Comment: I think I got it :) see the answer :)

Comment: Well your latest code works on all the questions correctly except for those that aren't answered and don't have a text box.  It's a little confusing, but all the questions should be inserted whether or not they are answered EXCEPT the ones that have a text box that is empty.
I think one problem is that the q variable won't have a value if a question is not answered -- it will have a yes or a no assigned to only if it is answered.  
To summarize, your code works correctly on the empty and filled text box questions but with the non text box questions, the unanswered ones need to be inserted too.

Comment: I was able to get it to work finally -- see above my comment to Jon Surrell.  I also used your technique of "if [skip] else [do something]" which I did not think of and which solved a major problem I was having in the flow.  Thanks for your help and troubleshooting!

Comment: Well no problem :) It was hard to understand what exactly you wanted to achieve, maybe just for me... Still I would consider being more clear next time and good luck!